# Creating folders from csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a number of folders from a csv file and then run a python script inside each. The following code is to create the folders. It runs but doesn't create anything!

```
import errno    
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

mountains_column_name = "mountains"

#read from the csv of mountains

data = pd.read_csv('1500mountains.csv', encoding='utf8')

#column called mountains has the names:
if mountains_column_name not in data.columns:
    raise ValueError("Missing Mountain column in input data")

mountains = data[mountains_column_name].tolist()


def mkdir_p(mountains):
    try:
        os.makedirs('\vince\Desktop\WhatMountainThat\dataset')
    except OSError as exc:  # Python >2.5
        if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and         
os.path.isdir('\vince\Desktop\WhatMountainThat\dataset'):
            pass
        else:
            raise
 mkdir_p(mountains)
```

I'd forgotten to call mkdir!  When I call it now I get the following :

TypeError: mkdir_p() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mountains'

Comment: Have you called the function `mkdir_p(mountains)` ?

Comment: is it necessary to use `pandas` here?

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh I am an idiot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that `your_list_from_csv` vaiable is list of dirs you want to create. Then create floders like so:

```
import os

path = "/your/path"
your_list_from_csv = ["dir1", "dir2"]

for new_dir in your_list_from_csv:
    dir_path = "{0:s}/{1:s}".format(path, new_dir)
    try:
        os.mkdir(dir_path)
    except FileExistsError as err:
        print("Folder Exists")
```

output:

```
$ ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 rszamszur rszamszur 4096 Nov  1 13:06 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 rszamszur rszamszur 4096 Nov  1 13:06 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 rszamszur rszamszur 4096 Nov  1 13:06 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 rszamszur rszamszur 4096 Nov  1 13:06 dir2
```

#### Edit

For Windows users out there you will need to provide path with disk partition while using backslashes instead. Example:

```
path = "c:\your\path"
```

Comment: This looks great. If I then want to run a script that will take a variable with the same name as the folder would I just nest that in this function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if the directory already exists, `FileExistsError` is raised. So you will probably need simpre try except block.  But basically this will create folders with names defined in `your_list_from_csv` variable under path which is defined in `path` variable

Comment: @VincentRyan you can either pass list of folders to crate. Or skip for loop and pass single item. BTW I've added try except block for recovering when folder already exists.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/vince/Desktop/WhatMountainThat/dataset/Mount Everest Himalayas'

Comment: @VincentRyan You are using windows which has different file structure than linux. Try like this: `path = "c:/vince/Desktop/WhatMountainThat/dataset"` (I guess this is probably on C drive)

Comment: @VincentRyan or with backslashes I'm not sure. `path = "c:\vince\Desktop\WhatMountainThat\dataset"`

Comment: That was it. Thanks. It created 82 of the 1500 holders I was hoping to put together. WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/vince/Desktop/WhatMountainThat/dataset/Jomolhari / Chomolhari Himalayas'

Comment: I think it was trying to create a subfolder which I didn't want it to do. I guess that is an issue with my csv?

Comment: @VincentRyan Are you trying maybe to create parent folder and subfolder at the same time? Or maybe the space before folder name causes problem.

Comment: I found it there were \ in some of the cells in the csv. That was causing the problems.

Comment: Yep you will probably need to escape thoose characters. Because otherwise it will try to create a subfolder in a folder which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah I cleaned them all out. It should now work perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VincentRyan Glad it worked. Can I get accepted answer?